# Want to use jsoneditor in react app, But it gives me error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. But I created a react app with react CLI and now I want to use jsoneditor in this app. The editor link I am showing here.
[JSON Editor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor)

as I import it in app like this import './plugins/jsoneditor/jsoneditor.js'; it throws me error[image]

the same plugin work's without any dependency as I include in script tag.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load an external library which is not supported by React. The editor you want to use has no React compatible component class yet. So If you try to import the file like you import other components, you will get errors.

So for now you have to include the Library as script tag only to use. wait till there is an update from the developer or try another library.

Or take a look at [React Json Editor](http://ismaelga.github.io/react-json-editor/) if it serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can load an external editor in react or any external JS file having Plain Javascript using [React.Lazy()](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/lazy) .

```
const MarkdownPreview = lazy(() => import('./MarkdownPreview.js'));
```

I had a similar issue while trying to Load ace JS editor on to my React app . It got resolved with this .